# gettext: change default .mo files location

Tags: c++, gettext

By-default gettext is searching .mo files in directory like this: `locale/en_EN/LC_MESSAGES`
In my case I need to configure the gettext to search for .mo files in folder without any locale-specification, for example `locale/LC_MESSAGES`.
Is there any possibility to configure gettext in that way? (I am using C++ version of gettext)

Comment: Did you look at https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/index.html

Comment: "I need to configure the gettext to search for .mo files in folder without any locale-specification" - why?

Comment: @FredrickGauss yes, it seems like there is no way to do this

Comment: @JesperJuhl some old project with already configured localization process

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully do this when using the win32 version of GNU gettext under C++ by referencing folders in the gettext function by using the "../../" folder convention. So, for example, if you have an mo file called filename.mo in the folder c:/locale then you can reference it as follows:

bindtextdomain("../../filename", "c:/locale");

At least, this trick worked for me under the win32 version of gettext. The trick is that in fact because of the way gettext references mo files based on the subfolder en_EN/LC_MESSAGES (in your example) this above call to bindtextdomain causes gettext to search under c:/locale/en_EN/LC_MESSAGES/../../filename.mo which is in fact equal to c:/locale/filename.mo. Also, in my tests, even if the c:/locale had no en_EN/LC_MESSAGES subfolder underneath it, it still worked (at least in my environment).